# Which command do you execute to open Gnome Disk Utility (Disks)?

Tags: command-line, gnome-disk-utility

I have tried `gnome-disk-utility` and it has failed. Yet again I have deleted the launcher for, 'Disks' which is gnome disk utility and now I can't see how I can open it. I am running 12.10.

Which command do you execute from the command-line to open Gnome Disk Utility (Disks)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`gnome-disks`

---

The auto-suggestion from package management sometimes helps out when you make a typo ( :) )

```
No command 'gnome-diskw' found, did you mean:
 Command 'gnome-disks' from package 'gnome-disk-utility' (main)
gnome-diskw: command not found
```

Comment: Thanks mate, this has been standing in my way as my PC hasn't been mounting DVDs and CDs when I place them in the player.

Answer (score 1):

You can launch **Disk Utility** (*gnome-disk-utility*) GUI using:

```
palimpsest &
```

[image: snapshot]

Comment: I installed `gnome-disk-utility`, but I have no `palimpsest` executable. What is missing?

Comment: @landroni you can check the executable provided in the package with `dpkg -L gnome-disk-utility`.. or are there some problems in the installation?

Comment: seems they've changed the name.. maybe it's `gnome-disks`  (rinzwind mentions that in his answer) from Ubuntu 12.10 and above.. it's `palimpsest` for Precise.

Comment: `dpkg -L gnome-disk-utility | grep palimpsest` returns empty. I guess it's indeed a name change in the binary, and this executable is no longer the same in Trusty.

Comment: the command lists all the files provided by the package.. you'd find what it's been renamed to..

Comment: `gnome-disks` works fine on Trusty. Thanks.