# How do I open Disk Utility in Xfce?

Tags: xfce, disk, gnome-disk-utility

On the back of [How do I open the Disk Utility in Unity?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/86724/how-do-i-open-the-disk-utility-in-the-unity-desktop-environment), how do you access `Disk Utility` in other DEs like Xfce? And what exact packages need to be installed to access this functionality?

Answer (score 13):

As per [Which command do you execute to open Gnome Disk Utility (Disks)?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/236581/which-command-do-you-need-to-execute-from-the-command-line-to-call-gnome-disk-ut), you need to install `gnome-disk-utility` and then execute:

```
gnome-disks
```

Alternatively, in Xfce you can go to `Settings > Disks`.

Answer (score 1):

In Xfce4, right click on the desktop, go to **Applications menu > Accessories > Disks**. This entry is only available after installing `gnome-disk-utility` package.